# Join two tables where all the rows share the same values in join table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
material
id
name

material_length
id
price
amount_on_stock
price
length
```

If I do this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM material JOIN material_length ON material.id = material_length.material_id
```

I get this result with some artificial data I added:

[image]

How do I select all the lengths that are shared across all materials?

For example, you can see that `pillar` and `pillar 2` share the same length: 8, Can I somehow select only the shared length number? So, in this case, it would be just 8 as both `pillar` and `pillar 2` has length variation of 8.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: What would you want to show for `material.id` on that row?

Comment: With SQL questions, always tag your DBMS please.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lengths shared across all materials:

```
select ml.length
from material_length ml
group by ml.length
having count(distinct ml.material_id) = (select count(*) from material);
```

This aggregates by `length` and counts the number of distinct material ids.  It then compares that number to the number of materials.